# Proof of the Canonical form for commuting vector field

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm reading proof of the John Lee's Smooth manifold, Theorem 9.46 and stuck at some point :

[image]
[image]

Why the underlined statement is true?

Let $q := \Phi(s_0) $. Then $t \mapsto \gamma(t):=(\theta_i)_t(q)$ is an integral curve of $V_i$ starting at $q$. So, in particular,  $\gamma^{'}(0) = V_{i, \gamma(0)}=V_{i,q} = V_{i,\Phi(s_0)}$. So, to show the underlined statement, it suffices to show that

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial s^{i}}|_{s_0} f( (\theta_i)_{s^i} \circ (\theta_1)_{s^{1}} \circ \cdots \circ (\theta_{i-1})_{s^{i-1}} \circ (\theta_{i+1})_{s^{i+1}} \circ \cdots \circ (\theta_k)_{s^{k}}(0, \cdots, 0, s^{k+1}, \cdots , s^{n})) = \gamma^{'}(0)f = \frac{d}{dt}|_{t-0}(f\circ \gamma) $$

Then how to show this equality rigorously ? How can we connect the $\frac{\partial}{\partial s^{i}}|_{s_0}$ -derivative to $\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}$-derivative? I want to understand this step desperately. Can anyone helps?

Comment: Please do not post images of text instead of the text itself. It is exclusive to many users and makes the post unsearchable to others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $s_0 = (s^1_0,\dots,s^n_0)$ is a point in $(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)^k\times\Omega$.
The point is that
if you let
$$q=(\theta_1)_{s_0^{1}} \circ \cdots \circ (\theta_{i-1})_{s_0^{i-1}} \circ (\theta_{i+1})_{s_0^{i+1}} \circ \cdots \circ (\theta_k)_{s_0^{k}}(0, \cdots, 0, s_0^{k+1}, \cdots , s_0^{n}) ,$$
then the expression in question is
$$
\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial s^{i}}\right|_{s^i = s^i_0} f\circ (\theta_i)_{s^i} (q).
$$
Do you see why that derivative is equal to $V_i|_{\Phi(s_0)}$ applied to $f$?

Comment: Thanks. Letting $t:=s^i$ and $t_0 = s_0^{i}$, we get the desired result : i.e., 
   $\frac{\partial}{\partial s^{i}} |_{s^i=s_0^{i}}f\circ (\theta_i)_{s^{i}}(q) = \frac{d}{dt}|_{t=t_0}f((\theta_i)_t(q)))= ((\theta_i)_t(q))'(t_0)f = V_{i}|_{(\theta_i)_{t_0}(q)}f = V_{i}|_ {(\theta_i)_{s_0^{i} }(q)}f = V_i |_{\Phi(s_0)}f$.

Comment: And..why the expression in the question is $\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial s^{i}}\right|_{s^i = s^i_0} f\circ (\theta_i)_{s^i} (q).$ ? In the expression, $(0, \cdots , 0, s^{k+1}, \cdots , s^n)$ seems to be variables. How the derivative $\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial s^{i}}\right|_{s^i = s^i_0}$ and the fixed element $q$ came out? 
    
    It seems to be possible but I don't understand it rigorously. I think that I don't know something about derivative at a point (in manifold theory) :)